# c# save directory between sessions

Tags: c#, session, configuration

Not really done this before so I wanted a few pointers.

In my app, users are able to pick a folder that the application looks in when it is started to pick up some input files.

What is the best way to save this information between sessions.

the old fashion way I would have done in the past would be to have a config.ini file and read and write to that the path. However I am sure there are better ways now.

I don't want to have to write to the registary as I want a app that can be installed and uninstalled simple by copying a folder or deleating the folder.

Is there any way to save configuration settings that the uesr can update and remian constant between sessions?

Cheers

Aaron

Comment: Is this an asp.net app? Silverlight? Desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the way is done now, is by writing these values to the [Application.Settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx); however, that's not too different than writing to any XML file and reading it on startup. Either alternative is almost equally simple.

Comment: So really no different to the past :) seperate file containing the settings. One last thing, this config file is plain text, is there any way to avoid that? Or am i missing some thing? Cheers

Comment: @DevilWAH the `Application.Settings` file is an XML file so I guess you can call it a `plain text` file in that sense, but if you want something in a different format (perhaps a binary file?), I would just you write my own class to handle this scenario. I'd imagine you would need to serialize an object containing the settings and save it to disk; then, on app start up, read the bytes in that file and reconstruct your object.

Comment: mmm might leave that for later then :), sounds fun but not something I want to take to much time on now. Still a bit new to c#, and would like to learn a bit more before getting in to that, another one to add to the todo list. I think its time I pick up a book and delve a bit more in to objects. Although I use them a bit I still ot lots to learn.

Comment: Oh cheers for the answer and comments though, cleared up a few questions I had. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

As [Icarus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636067/c-save-directory-between-sessions/7636095#7636095) said, you need a .settings file. You can specify that settings be [Scoped to the User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.userscopedsettingattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into using IsolatedStorage ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dzh4ws.aspx ).